# REST ASSURED API Automation run time error

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured, scribe

I downloaded jars and passed in Build path as well "scribejava-apis-2.5.3" and "scribejava-core-4.2.0"

---

code is below:

```
public class Basicfunc {

String Consumerkeys= "******************";
String Consumersecretkeys="************";
String Token="**********_*^%&-**************";
String Tokensecret="*********************";


@Test
public void getLatestTweet(){

    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses";
    Response res = given().auth().oauth(Consumerkeys, Consumersecretkeys, Token, Tokensecret).
    queryParam("count","1").
    when().get("/home_timeline.json").then().extract().response();


    String response = res.asString();
    System.out.println(response);
    JsonPath js = new JsonPath(response);
    System.out.println(js.getString("text"));

}
```

}

---

error is below:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/scribejava/core/model/AbstractRequest
        at io.restassured.internal.http.AuthConfig.oauth(AuthConfig.java:182)
        at io.restassured.internal.http.AuthConfig$oauth.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:152)
        at io.restassured.authentication.OAuthScheme.authenticate(OAuthScheme.groovy:35)
        at io.restassured.authentication.AuthenticationScheme$authenticate.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1265)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:822)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:152)
        at io.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:30)
        at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
        at io.restassured.filter.time.TimingFilter.filter(TimingFilter.java:56)
        at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:144)
        at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
        at io.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1749)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:822)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:57)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1755)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:822)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:57)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:171)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at twitter.api.test.Basicfunc.getLatestTweet(Basicfunc.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
        at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.scribejava.core.model.AbstractRequest
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 100 more

Comment: Please double check that `com/github/scribejava/core/model/AbstractRequest` is in the `scribejava-core-4.2.0` jar and that the `scribejava-core-4.2.0` is on the class path when running the test (the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` suggest that this is not the case)